# Spring loads two different instances when loaded with BeanFactory and ApplicationContext with a single spring.xml file

Tags: java, spring

I was writing some code to study different ways for getting bean from spring container. I have kept the code very simple to address the issue I had .

I have written below classes

**Triangle Class**

```
package org.studyspring.beanfactory;
public class Triangle {
    public String draw() {
        return "Triangle Drawn";
    }
}
```

**Spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
 <bean id ="triangle" class ="org.studyspring.beanfactory.Triangle"/>
</beans>
```

**Test class**

```
package org.studyspring.beanfactory;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class BeanFactoryTest {
private static BeanFactory factory;
private static ApplicationContext context;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupBeforeClass(){
        factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("./basicSpring/src/test/resources/spring.xml"));
        context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void getTriangleBean_WithBeanFactory(){
        Triangle triangle = (Triangle) factory.getBean("triangle");
        String message = triangle.draw();
        assertEquals("Triangle Drawn",message);
    }

    @Test
    public void getTriangleBean_WithApplicationContext(){
        Triangle triangle = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
        String message = triangle.draw();
        assertEquals("Triangle Drawn",message);
    }

    @Test
    public void triangleBean_ShouldBeSame_WithApplicationContextAndWithBeanFactory(){
        Triangle triangle = (Triangle) factory.getBean("triangle");
        Triangle triangle1 = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
        String message = triangle.draw();
        assertEquals(triangle,triangle1);
    }
}
```

I thought my testcase `triangleBean_ShouldBeSame_WithApplicationContextAndWithBeanFactory` should have been passed but actually it failed with below error

```
Expected :org.studyspring.beanfactory.Triangle@22c1609b
Actual   :org.studyspring.beanfactory.Triangle@45ad71f0
```

I am asking this question because I had below assumptions

1. when spring container initializes a bean its default scope is Singleton
2. spring container should use only one instance of bean
3. moreover `ApplicationContext` extends `BeanFactory` (indirectly)
4. We could use `BeanFactory` and `ApplicationContext` alternatively

My question is about the fundamentals ,***is it the correct behaviour by spring container to load two seperate instances each for beanFactory and ApplicationContext***?

Comment: A spring singleton is a singleton per context as you are creating 2 contexts you get 2  bean instances. Also you shouldn't be creating application contexts around the place, you should create it once and use dependency injection if you need a bean instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you create 2 different containers. You can make 2 ApplicationContexts

```
ApplicationContext context1;
ApplicationContext context2;
```

still there will be two different instances of Triangle in them

Comment: If I have two different classes where I need this bean , So if I would get the bean with the help of ApplicationContext at both classes then we will get the freshly constructed beans ?  which means if we modify properties of one bean they wont be visible in other class ?

Comment: Not 2 different classes but 2 different instances of the same class.